# Looking for KVM switch (over IP) with good linux client

Tags: linux, remote-access, keyboard-video-mouse

I have some ATEN CN6000 and i1708 KVM boxes and clients for them are made for windows and java. Java clients doesnt work neither on win or linux systems(I can run them with JavaRE but they dont connect to KVM box). Client for CN6000 on windows works quite well but a have huge problems with connect to i1708 with win client. So I'm looking for some good replacement. I'm aiming to KVM with linux client. Whether there are such ?

What kind of KVMs you are using and have good opinion about them?

Comment: Unfortunately, shopping and product recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic here on SF (4th point under "NOT about" in the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq)).

Comment: Beside that, every single KVM system I tried kind of sucks. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't use KVMs at all but I've seen HP's 'IP Console Switch G2 with Virtual Media & CAC' working, liked it and it has a linux client - so take a look if you get time.